# CentOS - SSH - File That Change Iunput Setup

Tags: centos, configuration, systemd, sshd

I use **CentOS 7** and I need to change the file that delivers the SSH configuration */etc/ssh/sshd_config* to */etc/ssh/sshd_config_other*.

This demand was due to a security automation that always overwrites the sshd_config and I dont have allow to change.

I tested changing the /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/sshd.service creating a variable to ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $ OPTIONS, but it dosent work.

Does anyone know a way to change the SSH configuration file for /etc/ssh/sshd_config_other ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/sshd.service` is just a link to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service`, and you should change this file by copying it first to `/etc/systemd/system/`, then editing this copy.

However, if your sshd.service file has the line

```
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/sshd
```

then you can simply add to file `/etc/sysconfig/sshd` a line

```
OPTIONS='-f /etc/ssh/sshd_config_other'
```

If you change systemd files you need to `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`, but I dont suppose you do for this change.